# Calling React setState() from external javascript module

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented the following external Service class which contains the React setState() and the React Component simply use it by importing the module. I know the following is call is valid in terms of javascript, but do you think it is a good practice to have the setState() in the external js module? Or will it cause any possible issue down the track?

```
import service from '../Service';
class View extends React.Component {
   ...
   someFunction = (value) => {
       service.extFunction(this, value);
   }
   ...
}
```

- External js calling setState()

```
class Service { 
    extFunction(component, value) {
        component.setState({key: value});
    }
}

const service = new Service();
export default service;
```

Comment: Why do you need such a module? I don't think it would cause any problems other than readability maybe.

Comment: we are trying to encapsulate the logic into their respective service module. The only thing that i could think of is externalising the setState to module makes the service module dependent to React's state.

Comment: But we doubt whether this practice (putting setState in other modules) would cause any weird issues as we move on to build more of these. So I wanna see if anyone out there have gone through this